# Argand Digram when arguments are equal

Tags: complex-numbers

I am helping a student to draw the following equation on complex plane:
$$\arg\left[z-\left(3+i\right)\right]=\arg\left[z-\left(1+3\,i\right)\right]$$

[image]

Can anyone explain why the dashed line to be neglected.

Answer (score 0):

This equation gives two rays up and down on the line $x+y=4$, where points between (1,3) and (3,1) will not lie on this locus. For instance the points (2,2), (3/2,1/2), (1,1,3/2),... do not satisfy the equation that
$$Arg[z-(3+i)]=Arg[z-(1+3i)].$$ For the point $2+2i$, we get LHS: $Arg(-1+i)=-3\pi/4$ but RHS: $Arg(1-i)=-\pi/4.$

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: You are welcome, you may now accept the answer.